# Foreign key mismatch

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my SQLite table structure

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_district (
    districtId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY not null,
    districtName TEXT unique NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_route (
    routeId INTEGER,
    districtId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tbl_district (districtId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    routeName TEXT NOT NULL,
    primary key (routeId , districtId)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_city (
    cityId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    routeId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES tbl_route (routeId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    cityName TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

If i execute

```
insert into tbl_district ( districtId, districtName) values (1,'Sri Lanka')
```

It works as it should

But if i execute

```
replace into tbl_district ( districtId, districtName) values (1,'Sri Lanka')
```

It gives following error

```
Error while executing query: foreign key mismatch - "tbl_city" referencing "tbl_route"
```

Any idea to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have data in tbl_city?

Comment: No, this is the initial data insert

Comment: why are you using a replace function? This function will first do a delete then an insert which probably interferes with the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) says that

> the parent key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index.

The `routeId` column is the parent key of the foreign key in `tbl_city`, but has no UNIQUE constraint.

(Your REPLACE statement is not directly related to this; it's just when the database happend to notice the error.)